# Uploading a large attachment using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to upload a large (> 4mb) attachment to an existing message in Office 365.  I am following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http

I have successfully created the upload session, and obtained a uploadUrl value that looks legitimate, it roughly matches the example in the documentation.  Then I start my PUT to this url, for the first byte range that I've selected.  I'm sure I'm setting the Content-Type, Content-Length and Contact-Range headers correctly. My problem is that I get http 401 (Unauthorized) in response. The error header returned is "The audience claim value is invalid for current resource..." and it regurgitates my url and it looks intact.

My theory is that I need to add another API permission to my application. I already have mail read.write, and that allows me to create a < 4mb attachment. If I need another permission, which one?  Or do I have some other problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0) on Resumable Uploads, you'll need any of `Files.ReadWrite`, `Files.ReadWrite.All` or `Sites.ReadWrite.All` permissions for a Delegated Work account.
If you're using an Application token, then you need `Sites.ReadWrite.All` permission.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good idea, but those permissions don't seem to have any effect. The documentation I'm looking at says this: "Do not specify an Authorization request header. The PUT query uses a pre-authenticated URL from the uploadUrl property, that allows access to the https://outlook.office.com domain."  And in fact, the url has a big long AuthToken value in it, so I would think that once I get the uploadUrl, I should have all the authentication I need.  Doesn't work though.

Comment: Yes, The token is part of the uploadUrl as a query param so you don't have to add your own Auth. But you mentioned that your Error is due to an invalid audience. Is the token you created the upload session with from the same application that created the session or are you using a On-Behalf-Of flow? Go to jwt.io or equivilent site and enter your accesstoken. Is the audience claim for the application that you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the insight - I have it working now, it was a problem with not requesting sufficient scopes when obtaining the token.

Comment: Jeff, can you please write here the solution?

Answer (score 0):

What were the permissions you were missing that you had to add out of interest? Was the docs clear from our perspective? I can see the Resumable file upload permissions is specific to SharePoint and can use "Files.ReadWrite, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All".

For mail message you'd need Mail.ReadWrite as per this doc for large file upload https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I've created a feedback item on the doc to get this updated. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6817

Answer (score 0):

You most likely you used the same HTTP-Client as for creating the Session. That Client needed a Graph Authentication. However the Endpoint for the Upload is Outlook and those audiences don't mix. The Url you got back when creating the Upload session already contains an appropriate AccessToken in the URL, but since your Client had a different one in the Header the Header took priority. Just use a clean Http-Client with the given URL and you should be fine.

Had the same issue right now and was able to fix it this way. Not sure if it was the same ~3 years ago.